# If $f$ is a bijective function such that $f:X \mapsto X$, is it always true that $ f(\{x\}) =\{f(x)\} \neq \emptyset \ \forall x \in X$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Working with the definition it seems to me that there must  be an $y \in X$ such that $f(x) = y$ and so $  f(\{x\}) = \{ f(x) \} =  \{y \} \neq \emptyset  $, but I am not sure.

Comment: In short, I think you are correct, but some of the notations you used are quite confusing. Please clarify your question and I'll get back to you.

Comment: @WilliamWei I think my doubt stems from a confusion about the meaning of the notation, but I tried to explain it further. Thanks a lot anyway

Comment: The statement is true for any function, regardless of whether it is a bijection or an endofunction (domain = codomain) or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For *any function $f : X \to Y$ whatsoever*, whether or not bijective, whether or not $Y=X$, it is true that for any $x \in X$, $f(\{x\})=\{f(x)\} \ne \emptyset$. This follows from the definition of a function: $f(x)$ is a well-defined single element of the set $Y$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was a pretty stupid question indeed. And also $ |\{f(x)\}| = 1$? Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.